# Angular 2 (click) doesn't work

Tags: angular

I can't understand where is a bug here.

**add.component.ts:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'counter',
    templateUrl: './add.component.html'
})
export class CounterComponent {
    public currentCount = 0;

    public incrementCounter() {
        this.currentCount++;
    }
}
```

**add.component.html:**

```
<h1>Counter</h1>

<p>This is a simple example of an Angular component.</p>

<p>Current count: <strong>{{ currentCount }}</strong></p>

<button (click)="incrementCounter()">Increment</button>
```

When I click on the button, nothing happens.

Comment: Create a plunker if possible

Comment: Are you getting any console errors?  This should work as far as I can tell.

Comment: Works as expected, here is a plunk: https://plnkr.co/edit/0eGfLSzZjhr9a6vtDhdC

Comment: Official documentation working sample https://embed.plnkr.co/?show=preview

Answer (score 1):

I have tested it in this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/vDEYeEYZyGvraRDN5kaf?p=preview) and it does work as expected. Apparently, something is wrong with your setup. What does the console say? (In your browser, press F12 and check for errors.)

Only difference is I used an inline template:

```
template: `<h1>Counter</h1>
<p>This is a simple example of an Angular component.</p>
<p>Current count: <strong>{{ currentCount }}</strong></p>
<button (click)="incrementCounter()">Increment</button>`
})
```

Comment: Thank you. The problem was in the wrong sequence of importing modules